# Property is not getting the added value when using static singleton

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a class 'Instances.cs' that contains other classes properties. This class is initialized only once using static singleton. Also each property has a check inside the get{}, that creates a new instance of this property when it's null. My propblem is that, when I'm trying to add some values to any of these properties, they just stay null. Also one thing to mention that these classes are placed into my service solution and accessed by service instance 'SVC'. I'm probably doing somethig wrong.. I will appreciate any help.

**Instance.cs where are placed all properties:**

```
public class Instances
{
    private SVC.User _user;
    private static Instances instance;

    public Instances()
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Singleton instance for this class
    /// </summary>
    public static Instances Get
    {
        get
        {
            return (instance != null) ? instance : new Instances();
        }
        set
        {
            instance = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Property that is always null
    /// </summary>
    public SVC.User User
    {
        get
        {
            return (this._user != null) ? this._user : new SVC.User();
        }
        set
        {
            this._user = value;
        }
    }
}
```

**Adding values to User class**

```
Instances.Get.User.Username = txtAdminName.Text;
Instances.Get.User.IsAdmin = true;
```

One more thing to mention, that User class contains properties: Username(string) and isAdmin(bool).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you didn't explicitly set the `Get` property, it returns a different instance every time (because it doesn't store the newly created instance).

You should implement it like this instead:

```
return instance ?? (instance = new Instances());
```

BTW, for your class to be a proper singleton, you should:

- make the constructor private
- remove the setter for the `Get` property

Also, `Get` is a pretty bad name for a property. Commonly used names for singleton instance include `Instance` and `Default`.

A good read on the singleton pattern: [Implementing the Singleton Pattern in C#](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx), by Jon Skeet

Comment: Ahh.. Yes you are right, i changed both the Get and User propreties as you showed and it works now, thank you @Thomas Levesque! :)

Answer (score 2):

That is not a singleton, because you can create multiple instances of the same class.
Try this:

```
public static Instances Get
{
   get { return instance ?? (instance = new Instances()); }
}
```